# Clarifying std::weak_ordering with C++20 Spaceship Operator for a Struct

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++20, spaceship-operator

I am learning about `std::strong_ordering` and `std::weak_ordering` in C++20. According to the docs, `std::strong_ordering` requires that equivalent values be indistinguishable, as opposed to `std::weak_ordering`.

When researching `std::weak_ordering` *(especially in the context of the spaceship operator, `<=>`)*, I generally encounter examples similar to the one below, which represents a multiplication expression:

```
// Represents a multiplication expression, the result of which is (multiplicand * multiplier)
struct Multiplication {
    int multiplicand;
    int multiplier;
};
```

This struct appears like it should be weakly ordered as different pairs of multiplicands and multipliers can evaluate to the same result, meaning equivalent values can be distinguishable (`Multiplication{3, 2}`, `Multiplication{6, 1}`, and `Multiplication{1, 6}` all technically represent 6).

However, the trivial approach for comparing different Multiplication structs actually returns an `std::strong_ordering` because multiplication results are ints and hence strongly ordered.

```
struct Multiplication {
    int multiplicand;
    int multiplier;

    // This returns std::strong_ordering by default
    auto operator<=>(Multiplication rhs) const 
    {
        return (multiplicand * multiplier) <=> (rhs.multiplicand * rhs.multiplier);
    }
};
```

Is it then my responsibility to explicitly annotate the return type as `std::weak_ordering` in this case to make it semantically accurate?

Comment: Yes, this is a purely semantic distinction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> According to the docs, `std::strong_ordering` requires that equivalent values be indistinguishable, as opposed to `std::weak_ordering`.

This is incorrect. It requires "substitutability", which [in the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/cmp.categories.pre#4) is defined as:

> the property that `f(a) == f(b)` is true whenever `a == b` is true, where `f` denotes a function that reads only comparison-salient state that is accessible via the argument’s public const members.

That's a very narrow definition, one that allows for `a` and `b` to have differences in data so long as they are not "comparison-salient".

That being said:

> Is it then my responsibility to explicitly annotate the return type as `std::weak_ordering` in this case to make it semantically accurate?

Yes. The compiler cannot know what is "substitutable" and what is not. This is a semantic property, and it is always up to the programmer to define it.

And yes, your `Multiplication` struct is not substitutable.

Comment: Thank you! However, I believe for the sake of this example, the default spaceship operator doesn't behave like the custom defined one in the question.

Comment: @RaisinCrab: Good point. I removed that bit.